# Why can't an xml comment contain two hyphens

Tags: xml, sgml

I was applying markdown comments in the xml comments of a config file when the XmlParser reported that two hyphens (`--`) are not allowed in xml comments.

Checking the [XML Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-comments), it appears that xml comment isn't designed to contain two hyphens for compatibility reasons with SGML parsers.

Why do SGML parsers disallow double hyphens in comments?

Comment: I don't think you will get a better answer than "because that's what the standard says"

Comment: Well, it's that's the only answer, then I have no choice :-(, though there might be better answer than that.

Comment: check out my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/20885152/582727

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[This page](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/SGMLComments.html#doubledash) outlines quite a bit of the HTML/SGML history, and the rather convoluted rules of those two consecutive hyphens (double dash).

The relevant part about SGML:

> To put it simply, the double dash at the start and end of the comment do not start and end the comment. Double dash indicates a change in what the comment is allowed to contain. The first -- starts the comment, and tells the browser that the comment is allowed to contain > characters without ending the comment. The second -- does not end the comment. It tells the browser that if it encounters a > character, it must then end the comment. If another -- is added, then it goes back to allowing the > characters.

Comment: [The section you're referring to](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/SGMLComments.html#doubledash). When I read what the SGML specs intended for `--` within the comment, my head spins around on the complexity it will introduce later on.

Comment: The advice to never use `--` inside a comment seems good to me. But, is there a standard way of escaping it? Suppose I want to create (and share) an output filter to ensure `foo -- bar` never causes a problem. Is there an SGML equivalent of `foo -\- bar`? (I'm sure it's not backslash though!) Or `&#45;` (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2233736/473249)), or something else? If we just replace `--` with `-` or `- -`, the escaping is not reversible.

Comment: @fazy Sorry, but it is a *comment*, something that is there just so explain what follows to a human reader with a high potential that no user of that document ever reads it. I really do not understand the point in insisting on double dashes as part of a comment.

Answer (score 17):

Because a double hyphen *is* the comment delimiter in SGML. The `<!` starts an SGML instruction, the `--` indicates the start or end of a comment. So basically it is for the same reason that a C++ comment cannot contain `*/`.

Comment: I think `-->` is the comment delimiter.

Comment: No, it is not. `<!` starts an SGML instruction, `>` ends it. Within an SGML instruction `--` both starts and ends a comment.

Comment: Ahh add your comment to the answer, this is illuminating because it means you could write <!someRelevantSgmlTag -- a comment -- someAttribute="blabla" -- another comment --> and the semantic meaning would be <!someRelevantSgmlTag someAttribute="blabla">

Comment: Ah, makes sense. `--> ` is actually two tokens, the `--` to delimit comment, and `>` to end SGML instruction. Now, I have an idea on where `<![CDATA[` ... `]]>` originated.

Comment: I've merged the comment.

Comment: There is also, of course, the <!DOCTYPE HTML longstringthatnooneremembers> declaration (thankfully shortened in HTML5)